# FFmpeg: real-time buffer[ ] [input] too full or near too full (101% of size: 3041280 [rtbufsize parameter]) frame dropped

Tags: c++, ffmpeg, directshow

I use the library of ffmpeg to decode stream from [TTQ HD Camera] and encode it to a rtmp stream.
but I receive a lot of warnings like the picture below.
i try to set qmin and qmax , it seems a little better. but still not totally resolve the problem.

```
encoder_context->qmin = 10;
encoder_context->qmax = 51;
```

who knows this is why ?

```
[dshow @ 04bfc640] real-time buffer [TTQ HD Camera] [video input] too full or near too full (101% of size: 3041280 [rtbufsize parameter])! frame dropped!
```

[image]

Comment: did you try to change [`max_picture_buffer`](https://www.ffmpeg.org/doxygen/0.6/libavformat_2options_8c-source.html#l00060)?

Comment: Thank you @wimh. I have set max_picture_buffer to a big number 800000000. It appears ok. but after a while , the warning above appear again . do I need to free some memory elsewhere after av_interleaved_write_frame ?

Comment: Sorry, I can't answer that. But maybe someone else knows...

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried increasing the `-rtbufsize` parameter to something larger than 3041280? If you have the RAM for it, try something like 2000M. It should be defined before the `-i` of the camera.

So something like:

```
ffmpeg -f dshow -video_size 1920x1080 -rtbufsize 2147.48M -framerate 30 -pixel_format bgr0 -i video=...
```

Note that the resolution and frame rate are just examples and you would have to fill in your values that you have used in the ffmpeg command already.